# Why does Venezuelan national football team wear burgundy uniform?

Tags: football, uniform

Usually, a national football team's uniform color uses the nation's flag color.

The Venezuelan national football team, however, wears a burgundy color uniform which has nothing to do with their flag.

Is there any particular reason or historical context for this? Wikipedia only states this, without explaining why burgundy was chosen:

> Venezuela made its international debut in the Central American and Caribbean Games held in Panama in 1938, wearing the vinotinto (burgundy) color.

Comment: Some associations have their own color kit that doesn't have much to do with their flag. A prominent example would be Germany. Their main kit is white & black while the flag is black/red/yellow.

Comment: Another article which mentions a few others: https://www.theguardian.com/theguardian/2012/nov/21/why-italian-teams-wear-blue . Belgium NT once played in white shirts under coach Guy Thys, cause of visibility when playing at night with floodlights, and is still often used as kit colour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an article (in Spanish, and used google translate) that states they lend sport uniforms from the Venezuelan Army, which were burgundy:

> Initially, the players wore a completely white uniform, while the Venezuelan Armed Forces used the famous wine color. The first to handle the concept of "Vinotinto" was the officer José Antonio Anzoátegui , who today is known as the pioneer of this nickname .
>
> From there it took several years for the nickname to be transferred to the soccer team. It was in the year 1938 , when the South American team participated in the Bolivarian Games, in Bogotá. The Venezuelan players did not have uniforms to play the tournament, so the National Guard offered to lend their sports clothing so that the national team could play.

[Source: goal.com](https://www.goal.com/es-cl/noticias/por-que-le-dicen-la-vinotinto-a-la-seleccion-venezolana/1mb611fmtkoxw17t8gqss0zuo1)

Comment: I added this valuable information to Wikipedia.